# Matching users based on their input and choosing from one of them

Tags: javascript, php, html, algorithm, web

I am trying to implement a situation, where users have the options to to pick the numbers 1-3 and then they again pick another set of numbers 1 to 3.

So the possible combinations of results would go:

- 1 & 1
- 1 & 2
- 1 & 3
- 2 & 1
- 2 & 2
- 2 & 3
- 3 & 1
- 3 & 2
- 3 & 3

I want to match the users that picked the same combinations (essentially putting them in the same category) and then later randomly select one of them from said category.

My approach to this was get the users input(which I've already implemented) and then put it into a database.

Then follow on by randomly selecting a user in that category.

After a user is selected then all users are taken out of the category and can repick two new options.

I am not sure if putting them in the database would be the best approach, how else could I do this?

Comment: You could use a regular file, but what's wrong with using a database?

Comment: Nothing Im looking for a better approach but seems like Ill just have to go with the database.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged php on your question, so perhaps this isn't applicable. But if you're using nodejs you could just initiate an array holding the users choices. This would be persistent, so as page requests come in that array could be referenced and updated. If you have the option of using nodejs I could put together a little jsfiddle for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either database or something like text file But if you want to check user name existence, database do the job much easier. the point is that in order to store users name who picked a sequence you can store each category in one field just separate them with commas ",". The only thing to do is to explode by comma and then you have an array contains username who picked that category.